# Cylinder 3 misfire after thermostat replacement valve

Tags: radiator, misfire, thermostat, replacements

I have 2003 Ford Expedition that had the heater not working because my thermostat was broken open. I then got a code to replace the thermostat. I need to take a long drive so I took it to a shop to have the thermostat replaced. They did as well as flush the radiator and replace the coolant and reset my computer. When I left and was at a light on brake the car shook and the engine light came back on. I ran to have the code read myself since the shop said it was impossible. It read cylinder 3 misfire. I took the printout and car back and the shop told me just yo drive it since it was reset. Any ideas???

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the CEL still showing? Is it still running bad? If not, I agree with the shop. If it's still happening, I'd suggest the shop needs to figure out what's going on.

Comment: The light is still on it still shakes a little while on in drive but braked. I’m just worried to drive it with the light showing that could it cause more damage?

Comment: Yes, it can cause more damage. The biggest threat is to the catalytic converter if the computer isn't smart enough to turn of the fuel injector to the #3 cylinder.